# The image field disappears and the view is set to disabled

Tags: views

We've had this happen several times now and can't figure out what is happening. We only realize it has happened when we try to go to a view that is affected.

All views with an image field in them are affected. The field will disappear and the view will be set to disabled. We have to go in and re-add the image field and enable the view.

Has anyone seen anything like this? We've had it happen on two different D9 sites.

Comment: "Field is removed from a view and the view is set to disabled"-- this can happen when you delete a field... I'm guessing you are not deleting the field though in this case.

Comment: Nope, field hasn't been touched in weeks since we originally created the content types.